# 68 ms vs 793ms. Same query, almost the same analyze. Why is it happening?

Tags: postgresql, performance

The query:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM metrics
WHERE f1 = [randomly generated]
AND f2 = [randomly generated]
AND f3 = [randomly generated]
AND f4 = [randomly generated]
AND f5 = [randomly generated]
```

I ran it twice.
Once I got this result:

```sql
Aggregate  (cost=4464.87..4464.88 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=68.059..68.059 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using metrics_default_filters on metrics  (cost=0.69..4459.30 rows=2229 width=16) (actual time=0.928..67.875 rows=2160 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((f1 = 'c8e1eb22-a627-3daa-884c-2205cf78d075'::uuid) AND (f2 = 'c8e1eb22-a627-3daa-884c-2205cf78d075'::uuid) AND (f3 = 'c8e1eb22-a627-3daa-884c-2205cf78d075'::uuid) AND (f4 = '31c2aea8-5c8e-373f-bbe8-478da241e1fc'::uuid) AND (f5 = '0a25865b-970a-3281-b8de-aac852124754'::uuid))
Planning Time: 0.503 ms
Execution Time: 68.143 ms
```

And here, when the values of the filters are a bit different, I got a different result:

```sql
Aggregate  (cost=4030.42..4030.43 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=792.934..792.935 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using metrics_default_filters on metrics  (cost=0.69..4025.39 rows=2012 width=16) (actual time=1.370..792.623 rows=2160 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((f1 = 'c8e1eb22-a627-3daa-884c-2205cf78d075'::uuid) AND (f2 = 'c8e1eb22-a627-3daa-884c-2205cf78d075'::uuid) AND (f3 = 'c8e1eb22-a627-3daa-884c-2205cf78d075'::uuid) AND (f4 = '23ea1baf-6ab4-3aba-adc9-ce1e94afe80f'::uuid) AND (f5 = '58cafb7b-4d79-3262-9b6a-b2a011ccb186'::uuid))
Planning Time: 0.504 ms
Execution Time: 793.023 ms
```

I got this big variation already a few times.

This DB is only for testing so no other load is running on it.

The table has generally 23m rows.

Why do you think this happens?

Comment: I think you might want to run `explain` with the `buffers` option. Please also add the full table and index definitions. When was the table last vacuumed?

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I've noticed that it might be because the first query hit the cache.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the suggestion of @mustaccio I've noticed, via the `BUFFER` explanation that my query just hit the cache.

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess, but GUIDs being basically random numbers are causing key depth and page split issue.  If so, this is a pretty good example of why GUIDs should not be used as keys.